# How to disable growl on iterm2 with mac os 10.8.x?

Tags: iterm, growl

How to disable growl on iterm2 with mac os 10.8.x ? I don't want notifications everytime a tmux session becomes idle...

Answer (score 3):

Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Notifications > uncheck 'Enable Growl Notifications'

Answer (score 0):

In Growl's preferences you can edit which applications have permission to Growl.